# how to exclude a event in recurring events in full calendar

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

i want to exclude single event on the full calendar, i don't know how to do that?

i tried to use excludedDate: {days: } attriibute but id doesnot works
i want to make thsi code to exclude single event from recurring events, i tried but its not working in the ui

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarComponent } from 'ng-fullcalendar';
import { Options } from 'fullcalendar';
import { EventSesrvice } from './event.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  calendarOptions: Options;
  displayEvent: any;
  events = null;
  @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) ucCalendar: CalendarComponent;
  constructor(protected eventService: EventSesrvice) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.calendarOptions = {
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: false,
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
      },
      events: []
    };
  }
  loadevents() {
    this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(data => {
      this.events = data;
    });
  }
  clickButton(model: any) {
    this.displayEvent = model;
  }
  dayClick(model: any) {
    console.log(model);
  }
  eventClick(model: any) {
    model = {
      event: {
        id: model.event.id,
        start: model.event.start,
        end: model.event.end,
        title: model.event.title,
        allDay: model.event.allDay
        // other params
      },
      duration: {}
    };
    this.displayEvent = model;
  }
  updateEvent(model: any) {
    model = {
      event: {
        id: model.event.id,
        start: model.event.start,
        end: model.event.end,
        title: model.event.title
        // other params
      },
      duration: {
        _data: model.duration._data
      }
    };
    this.displayEvent = model;
  }
}
```

not getting any error message also

i have tried with the attribute excludedDate: new Date('2017/8/29') but not working

Comment: Where in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events) does "excludedDate" get mentioned as an option? I can't see it in that page or any other. Where did you get the idea for that?? Was it just a guess or something? Anyway since you didn't provide any actual event data, we have no idea how you're specifying recurrence (if at all) so we can't help you easily.

Comment: Anyway I don't think you can exclude a specific day using the simple recurring events functionality. You might be able to do it via the [RRule plugin](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin) but you'd have to study the RRule spec to see if it's possible to do such a thing. You can research it without too much trouble. Check it out, and try something if you find it. If you get stuck, ask again

Comment: If that isn't possible, your only other options I can think of are: split the recurring sequence into two separate sequences, the first one ending before the date you wish to exclude, and the second starting again after that date. Or alternatively, you'd have to write some code to delete the specific event again after it's been loaded into the calendar via the recurrence rules (but I'm not even sure how easy/possible it is to identify a single instance of a recurrence in fullCalendar). [getEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents) might return them individually - try and see.

Comment: i have the data actully  let data: any = [
            {
                title: 'Event Title 1',
                dow: '1, 2, 3, 4, 5',
                startTime: '02:00',
                endTime: '04:00',
                startRecur: '2019-09-15',
                endRecur: '2019-10-15'
            }
        ];
        return of(data);

Comment: im truing to do exclusion but not working i have one articvle where using pure javascript they are doing but using angular i m not getting https://jsfiddle.net/alelase/gz6mcon1/ go through this link please help me

Comment: he reason "excludedDate" works in the above JSFiddle is due to some custom code in the "eventRender" callback which takes notice of it. It's not built into fullCalendar. So if you want to use that option you need to re-use that eventRender logic in your own solution.

Comment: still not getting how to do the process! please help

Comment: you need to define the same "eventRender" callback in your fullCalendar setup.